# Error in calling a function with two outputs in c++ in Linux ubuntu

Tags: c++, linux, function

I have a c++ program which return two values, without any input as `[o1 o2] = myfunc()`
The first output (`o1`) is float with around 20 decimal values and second output (`o2`) is integer around 1000 and 2000.

I have another c++ program as main.cpp including:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>
#include "myfunc.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
float x;
int y;
boost::tie(x, y) = myfunc;
std::cout << "x == " << x << ", y == " << y << std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

But after running the command `g++ main.cpp -o main`, i face with the error as follows:

`main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:12:30: error: cannot convert ‘float*’ to ‘real_T* {aka double*}’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void myfunc(real_T*, real_T*)’`

---

Edit - *myfunc* has the type:

```
void myfunc(real_T *gbest, real_T *MaxIt);
```

Comment: instead of explaining what you do, can you create a simple example?

Comment: What does it mean by simple example? Since I am newcomer in c++, I think, my problem is in calling a function with two outputs. Is there any guidance?

Comment: There's no such thing, and you didn't show `myfunc`.

Comment: I added `myfunc` function in the below. My main concern is that, how can i call the two outputs of the 'myfunc' in another c++ program such as i was doing in above?

Comment: You should edit your question to add information, not create an answer. Perhaps you want your function to return a [tuple](http://en.highscore.de/cpp/boost/datastructures.html) ?

Comment: See [this](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)

Answer (score 4):

[Thats](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19981211/2746744) a function with two parameters that are pointers to real_T. Just call it!

```
real_T gbest;
real_T MaxIt;
myfunc(&gbest, &MaxIt);
```

Comment: I added your suggestion in my `main.cpp` program which i faced with this error: `/tmp/ccXjnJ3u.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `pso(double*, double*)' collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: The linker did not find a library with the code for pso. You are missing it, or the sequence of linking is wrong.

Comment: The sequence is:  int main()
{
real_T gbest;
real_T MaxIt;
pso(&gbest, &MaxIt);

std::cout << gbest << std::endl;
std::cout << MaxIt << std::endl;
return 0;
}
Is there any wrong?

Comment: The code looks correct. You just don't seem to link the library where pso is in. Thats some setting in your project setup or your makefile